# PHP files returns 1 instead of the logged in user name in another PHP file

Tags: php, html, joomla

I have a joomla website and have a PHP file in the root folder which fetches the current logged user perfectly.

I have another folder 'Files' which contains other HTML & PHP files. I need to kfetch the current logged user to work with these other HTML files.

```
Get_user.php   // in the ROOT folder of the JOomla website and works fine !

define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );


require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$user = JFactory::getUser();

$uname =  $user->username;
echo $uname;
//return $uname;
```

And this is my test.php file placed in `http://www.mywebsite.com/files/test.php`

```
 <? php
    $uname =  include 'http://www.mywebsite.com/Get_user.php';
    echo $uname;
  ?>
```

This always returns 1 where as i would like to have the user name. I tried with RETURN but doesn't work.

I have searched a lot in the forum but nothing seems to be working for me.

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be `return`.

Include it with path, not url.

**test.php**

```
<?php
    $uname =  include(__DIR__ . '/../Get_user.php');
    echo $uname;
?>
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks a lot ! :-)